# Generating Variants of a String According to Rules

Tags: string, algorithm

**What I'm hoping to get as an answer:**

I'm hoping someone can tell me the general class(es) of algorithms which solve these types of problems. Ideally, the algorithms could be run in parallel, but I am still very interested in algorithms which can only be executed sequentially. Specific algorithm names or literature references would be much appreciated :)

**What I've done so far:**

I basically approached this using some brute force methods involving generating all permutations of a given string length and then filtering out ones that don't match the set of rules. I don't like this approach though, as it is obviously quite slow and quickly becomes limited by my computing power (1 PC) and the size of the string. I started coming up with little optimizations to this approach, but felt like I must be re-inventing the wheel and there is likely a set of algorithms out there already for solving these kinds of problems.

### Problem description:

Consider a string like the following:

> ABCDBEACBDECDBAACBE

I'm trying to figure out efficient methods for generating ALL permutations of a string which follow a set of rules/conditions.

### Examples of Rules:

---

## Simple example:

1. There must be at least 2 differences from the original string
2. The differences must be in the alphabet set (A,B,C,D,E)

An example of a single, valid permutation, given the above rules would be:

**DE** CDBEACBDECDBAACBE

---

## Complicated rule set example 1:

1. There must be at least 2 differences from the original string
2. The differences must be in the alphabet set (A,B,C,D,E)
3. **NEW:** Differences must occur within defined index ranges of the string
4. **NEW:** Each range must 2 have differences

So, given the original string, let's say we have the following ranges defined:

> [(0,4), (8,14)]

This would look like:

> [ABCDB]EAC[BDECDBA]ACBE

And a valid permutation example is:

**BD** CDBEACB **AB** CDBAACBE

---

## Complicated rule set example 2:

1. There must be at least 2 differences from the original string
2. The differences must be in the alphabet set (A,B,C,D,E)
3. Differences must occur within defined index ranges of the string
4. Each range must have 2 differences
5. **NEW:** Differences must be a specific combination, let's say "AB"

Ranges:

> [(0,4), (8,14)]

A valid permutation example is:

B **AB** DBEACB **AB** CDBAACBE

---

## Complicated rule set example 3:

1. There must be at least 2 differences from the original string
2. The differences must be in the alphabet set (A,B,C,D,E)
3. Differences must occur within defined index ranges of the string
4. Each range must have 2 differences
5. **NEW:** Ranges can overlap

Ranges:

> [(0,4), (3,7)]

This would look like:

> [ABCD[B]EAC]BDECDBAACBE

A valid permutation example is:

ABC **ADB** ACBDECDBAACBE

---

Comment: Those don't look like [permutations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) at all. If you're asking for some library that have these things implemented, that's off topic. If you're asking for code, it would be good to show your brute force method (at least in pseudo-code). Also, just to clarify, you have 4 different sets of rules and you want code for each of them, correct? That would probably be better split into 4 different questions, or just pick the most complex one or two and try to simplify any given code to work for the simpler ones.

Comment: Is your alphabet always `[A, B, C, D, E]`? Are the strings always a fixed length? How many ranges do you expect and how large are those ranges? Just how complicated are the rules? Brute force is an excellent way to handle the rule set examples you've provided, because the number of permutations in those small ranges is really small. And in fact if the alphabet is always just 5 symbols, then even 10-character ranges wouldn't be unthinkable to solve with brute force. (5^10 is less than 10 million.)

Comment: I would argue that these are indeed permutations, albeit with constraints. In my combinatorics class we had similar (but simpler) questions, but were simply interested in counting rather than generating permutations. Unfortunately I don't know a general class of algorithms for this but I can say one thing. The constraints here are being stated very declaratively. I think thinking about constraints in terms of recursion (for e.g. ranges) will be better. What have you tried? Also, have you thought about posting on theoretical computer science stack exchange as well?

Comment: @JTrana These are not permutations. The original string contains 4 `A` characters. The simple example case contains only 3. By definition, the string in the simple example is not a permutation of the original string. Similar situations follow in the additional examples.

Comment: I apologize for any confusion I have caused by the incorrect use of the term "permutations". I'm not sure what a better term would be in this case. 

@jim-mischel: For some of the problems that I am looking at, the alphabet is the same. However, the string lengths could be much longer (maybe as long as 800), so the problem space does become quite large. The rules don't become much more complicated than what I have shown, just slight variations.

Perhaps I will try to come up with a single example. I want to find an approach that generates as few nonvalid "permutations" needing to be filtered.

Comment: I guess I looked at this as a permutations problem because of my first approach. Consider the original string as part of the condition/rule that limits the number of differences. My first approach was to solve this by generating all possible permutations of a string of length N using any characters in the alphabet [A,B,C,D,E]. I then filtered out any generated strings that didn't match all of the rules/conditions.

Comment: When the rule is that there must be two differences, the number of combinations that don't satisfy the rules is very small. For example, given a 4-character range, there are 625 possible combinations. Of those, only a small number will not have at least two differences. Your primary problem is generating the combinations, not determing in they conform to the rules. And there's just no way other than brute force to generate all the possible combinations (which is what you said you want). That's my long-winded way of saying that I don't understand what you're trying to optimize.

Comment: @jim-mischel I see what you're saying. Again, perhaps a wording problem on my part. Essentially, I was hoping to come up with a solution that is faster than a brute force -> filtering approach. This is mostly because of the limitations of brute force with long strings. After that, it's somewhat open-ended. I think Peter's answer might be an example of a solution that I am looking for. I don't know if there are better approaches, but it looks promising as an improvement over my current brute-force approach.

Comment: @twalberg Yeah, you're right. The strings are not. But how about the substitutions? I guess what I mean is that the solution space of differences is what you're trying to permute over. That's what was going through my head and I'm glad you called me out on this detail because I don't want to confuse other people.

Answer (score 1):

### Suggested approach

I would recommend you read up on a [deterministic finite automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton).

The way I would attempt to model this kind of problem is to turn the problem into a state machine that is able to recognise strings of the type that you want based on feeding characters in one at a time.

Once you have a state machine, you can use dynamic programming to count the number of matching strings that can be generated by starting in a particular state.  (The state incorporates knowing how many characters have been generated so far, and the progress in each of your rules.)

With the results of this dynamic programming, you can generate the k^th lexicographically ordered example of a matching string in time O(n) where n is the length of the string.

However, the cost of solving the dynamic programming will vary a lot depending on the complexity of your rule set.

### Example

For your example 3:

```
There must be at least 2 differences from the original string
The differences must be in the alphabet set (A,B,C,D,E)
Differences must occur within defined index ranges of the string
Each range must have 2 differences
```

the state would need to include the following information:

```
Number of differences in first range (0,1,2)
Number of differences in second range (0,1,2)
```

so there would be a total of 9 states to model.

For a system with R ranges, each requiring D differences, there would be (D+1)^R states required (fewer if the ranges do not overlap).

Comment: This looks really promising. I'll do some reading based this info and update with what I find. Thank you!